# LaTeX formatting with "A", "B" instead of 'Zero', 'One'

Tags: appendices

I am using a folder system in LaTeX where I have a folder for each chapter and appendix with their respective `chapter.tex` or `appendix.tex` files. I then include them in the `main.tex` file like:

```
%% APPENDICES %%
\appendix
\include{appendix/appendix1}
\include{appendix/appendix2}
\include{appendix/appendix3}
\include{appendix/appendix4}
```

In the `appendix1.tex` and the following appendix `.tex` files, I have the following:

```
\chapter{...some title...}
...some text...
```

The output however, is not how I want it. It outputs:

```
-------- Output : ---------

Appendix One
...some title...
...some text...

-------- I want : ---------

Appendix A
...some title...
...some text...
```

EDIT: I have figured out why it is behaving this way. I had the following package change the title format of my chapters:

```
% Make chapter numbers into string words 1 -> ONE
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{\vspace *{40\p@ }{\parindent \z@ 
\raggedright \normalfont \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \Huge \bfseries 
\@chapapp \space \Numberstring{chapter} \vskip 10\p@ \fi #1\par \nobreak \vskip 30\p@ }}
\makeatother
```

This causes "Appendix A" to turn into "Appendix One" and so on. I want to change this behaviour. Is there a way for me to undo this command at a specific place in the document?

Comment: As long as we don't know how you configure your document how are we suppose to help with this? In the default classes `\appendix` changes `\chapter` to use upper case letter, if you get something else, you have a different setup of which you have told us nothing.

Comment: @daleof, I have figured out the cause of this and added it into an edit. I still don't know how to change the behaviour in regards to the appendixes though.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I woulod remove everything from \makeatletter to \makeatother, just to see what the defualt is like.

Answer (score 1):

Without any testing (you should provide a full but minimal example) you can probably get away with

```
\makeatletter
\let\normal@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{\vspace *{40\p@ }{\parindent \z@ 
\raggedright \normalfont \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \Huge \bfseries 
\@chapapp \space \Numberstring{chapter} \vskip 10\p@ \fi #1\par \nobreak \vskip 30\p@ }}
\makeatother
...
\appendix
\makeatletter
 \let\@makechapterhead\normal@makechapterhead
\makeatother
```